# Autohotkey - Send Left control on long press otherwise send Enter

Tags: autohotkey

Here is my script. Capslock is mapped to send Left control on long press,otherwise send an escape. This is working as expected.

```
SetCapsLockState, alwaysoff
Capslock::
    Send {LControl Down}
    KeyWait, CapsLock
    Send {LControl Up}
    if ( A_PriorKey = "CapsLock" ){
        Send {Esc}
    }
    return

; Send left control when long pressed, otherwise behave a normal enter key
Enter::                
    send {LControl Down}
    KeyWait, Enter, T5
    Send {LControl Up} 
    if ( A_PriorKey = "Enter" ){
        Send {Enter}
    }
    return
```

However Enter key is not waiting for the long press, it is timing out quickly.This is not my expectation. It should behave like the above snippet

Comment: How long are you expecting the time out to be with the `Enter` key? You have a 5 second time out defined for the latter, but nothing for the former.

Comment: My expectation is, it shouldn't timeout like the Capslock binding. I tried with 5seconds, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding the issue correctly, this should do what you require:

```
Enter:: 
SendInput, {LCtrl Down}
Sleep, 100
KeyWait, Enter
SendInput, {LCtrl Up}
if ( A_PriorKey = "Enter" ){
    Send {Enter}
}
return
```

Also, I assume you have the catch at the end to pass through a single Enter keystroke. If that isn't the case, and you're wanting to pass through all of them (while Enter is held down), the following will accomplish that.

```
~Enter:: 
SendInput, {LCtrl Down}
Sleep, 100
KeyWait, Enter
SendInput, {LCtrl Up}
return
```

Comment: Any idea why this does not work alphabet keys? I tried using key `f` but unlike Enter, the letter `f` is never sent on quick release.

Comment: It works by prepending `$`, i.e. using `$f::` as the hotkey. For some reason `Enter` doesn't seem to require it.

Comment: @tejasvi88 I would refer to the `{RAW}` modifier when using `SendInput` for alphanumeric output. See Example #4 here: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#ExSendInputRaw